# Xcode Archive does not match with my build value after Xcode auto update to 14

Tags: ios, xcode, build, version, testflight

Good day,

Just now my Xcode auto update from version 13 to 14.

After it update, I continue to build my app. I found the UI design a bit different with previous, but so far I manage to find the setting that I fill in usually.

As usual, I increase my build number from 1.1.20 to 1.1.21.
[image]
However, after I archive, I found that version is not follow what I have key in (1.1.21), it written there 1.1.2, looks like it does not get my value to do the archive.
[image]

And if I continue to Validate app or Distribute App, I will hit `metadata/info.plist mismatch. the value for bundle_version in the metadata.xml file does not match the value for CFBundleVersion in...`

I even restart `Xcode`, restart Mac still the same, even I try change my build number to 1.1.3 or some other number, the result still the same.
Even I change my project format to `Xcode 13.0-compatible` still the same.

1 hour ago, I was still able to build the App before the `Xcode` auto update. After I auto update then it hit this issue.

May I know where is my mistake?

My temporary solution is edit the `info.plist` to proceed first.

In the `info.plist` file, I change the following value to the build number I want:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.1.21</string>
```

Comment: any solution? I have same issue after updating to Xcode 15

Comment: @MianJawadAhmad, no proper solution from me at this moment.
Temporary what I do is manually edit the info.plist to the correct version and continue to archive.

Comment: @MianJawadAhmad, I update in my question because its easier to read in formatted code, you can refer the last part.

Answer (score 6):

So as you have mentioned the Temporary, I will explain that in details.

I have also faced the same issue after upgrading from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14.

The temporary solution is to put the version name and build number directly in the info.plist as give below.

[image]