# Xcode archive uses 1.0 (1) instead of correct version number

Tags: xcode, archive, watchos

This is a problem others have faced but the resolutions I have seen offered don't seem to work in my situation. (See [Xcode is not archiving to the specified version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759809/xcode-is-not-archiving-to-the-specified-version-number)  and [Xcode Archive does not match with my build value after Xcode auto update to 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776064/xcode-archive-does-not-match-with-my-build-value-after-xcode-auto-update-to-14))

I am using Xcode 14.2 to create a watch app, building for "Any watchOS device(...)". When I create an archive, Xcode labels version 1.0 (1), which does not match my settings.

Any ideas on what I could try to remediate this?

What I have tried:

- Clean the build folder
- Hardcode the version numbers in the target's "Info" tab
- Letting App Store Connect auto-manage my build number when I submit the build for validation (it goes to 1.0 (8) given that I've previously had a 1.0 (7) build).
- Add the CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString parameters to the plist for the target.

## My archive

[image]

## My target settings for the "watchOS" target:

**"General" tab:**

[image]

**"Info" tab: **

The values for "Bundle version" and "Bundle version (short)" appear to be hard-coded. If I edit them and move off the tab and then come back to it, they return to "$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)" and "$(MARKETING_VERSION)" respectively.

[image]

**"Build Settings" tab:**

These match what's in the "General" tab.

[image]

(FWIW, my settings for the "watchOS Intents Extension" target march the settings above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the Build Settings of the iOS target in my watch-only app. Specifically, `Build Settings --> Versioning --> Current Project Version` and `Marketing Version`.

This workaround worked for me... but I don't consider it a long term fix.